# Add a subdomain to Office 365

Tags: powershell, dns, subdomain, office365

I have an Office 365 E3 trial version. I Have a domain called **training.me**. I create a subdomain  called  **sales.training.me** and added the subdomain sales.training.me  to my office E3 trail version. I added the TXT record of course and wanted to verify the subdomain  **sales.training.me**  but  even after more than 48 hours it's not yet verified. I did the same procedure though Powershell and it was not successful too.
Does this mean that I can not add a subdomain without adding first the root domain first?
In this case If I have to create many domains, each for a single Office365 Tenant, should I buy as many domains as Tenant?. In this case , is there a cheaper way to have many domains for each E3 Office365.

Comment: Where did you add the TXT record?

Comment: I added TXT DNS record at sales.training.me.   I have at least 6 subdomains,    xxxxxx.training.me. I added all Txt records at ccorresponding subdomains. None of them worked fine. (not verified)